# Priority_queue functor use C++

Tags: c++, functor

I have stumbled upon some weird use of priority_queue, I would love to obtain some proper explanation of why on earth it's plausibile/valid to use something like this in priority_queue declaration:

```
typedef priority_queue<RandomContainer, **vector<RandomContainer>**, FunctorName> NewQueueName;
```

Let's say we've got some struct called SPerson:

```
struct SPerson
{ 
   int age; 
   string name; 
   string surname; 
};
```

and some functor which will be helpful to sort all elements of queue accordingly to our likeing:

```
struct TheWayILike
{ 
   bool operator()(const SPerson &name1, const SPerson &name2) 
   { 
      if(name1.name > name2.name) return true; 
      if(name1.name < name2.name) return false; 

      return false; 
    } 
};
```

Now we can declare our priority_queue which will be based upon elements from the struct and which will be ordered by functor called TheWayILike.

```
priority_queue<SPerson, TheWayILike>
```

or shorter way by using typedef and single name like so:

```
 typedef priority_queue<SPerson, TheyWayILike> newNameForPQ;
```

but somehow it's wrong and I have to add following line: vector

Question:

**Why on earth do I have to squize my personally customized data types into vector ?**

Why it must be a vector and why should I use it anyway ?

Why do I need to fill my data into vector ? I haven't read about it in official priority_queue documentation, so I would love to obtain some easy to understand explanation for rookie programmer.

Cheers!

Comment: The `Container` is only a template parameter. It tells `priority_queue` what to use internally, you do not have to provide an instance of this container! In other words, create your queue like so: `priority_queue<SPerson, vector<SPerson>, TheWayILike> myPQ` and push your SPerson elements in it: `myPQ.push(a); myPQ.push(b); ...`

Answer (score 3):

You dont' have to. But look at the declaration of the `priority_queue` class template:

```
template<
    class T,
    class Container = std::vector<T>,
    class Compare = std::less<typename Container::value_type>
> class priority_queue;
```

You can't provide a custom comparator type argument unless you also provide the underlying container to hold the data in. The author of the line above decided `vector` was the best choice. Any other container that fits the requirements can also be used, e.g. `deque`, but `vector` proves to be best for most applications so it is the default.

Comment: Specifically, the container needs to fulfill a specific API and support random-access iterators, which ``vector`` and ``deque`` both do.

Comment: So basically I can't use ONLY basic struct, as a container that will be used in priority_queue, but I have to reassign/copy all data from struct to vector, deque or any other container before using priority_queue ? Is that right ?

Comment: If you want to use the `priority_queue` type of the line above, yes. If you can use your "own" `priority_queue` specialization and your container fulfills the requirements, you can just let it use your container type and move your container object into the `priority_queue`.

Comment: @JamieRandall: You make it sound as if there is a bunch of extra work being done because you are using a custom type with a custom comparator. There is not. The only thing you have to do differently is in how you declare the `priority_queue` (the template parameters you provide). After that, the rest of the work is all being done by the `priority_queue`, and it is the exact same amount of work that is done for any other type with any other comparator.